# Deleting images at my personal cloud with PHP

Tags: php, directory, cloud, storage, image-uploading

I'm working at a personal cloud where my gf can store her photos because her iCloud is full.

Basically, this is what is making everything works:

```
<?php
$dirname = "uploads/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}", GLOB_BRACE);

usort($images, create_function('$b,$a', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
foreach($images as $image) {

echo '
 <a href="'.$image.'">
 <img class="img-grid" src="'.$image.'" />
 </a>';
}

?>
```

[And it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OErv.jpg).

It's working perfectly but she needs a tool for deleting already uploaded images. Assuming she is only using this site at her smartphone, i've planned 3 ways of doing this although I dont know how to do it.

---

[1st: A "X" at every image for deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nj2y.jpg)

**PROS**: Easy for her //
**CONS**: Touchscreen miss click

---

2nd: A table with all images retrieved from dir and 'delete' button

**PROS**: Probably the easiest for programming? // **CONS**: Ugly

---

3rd: An "image preview" with delete button when clicking

**PROS**: Beauty and useful // **CONS**: Probably weird for mobile

---

So, which one of the 3 can be a good solution for her and how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Edit2: inserting "how to do it"
Edit3: sorry bad english, 'm from BR land

---

Comment: check to see if the file exists, then unlink(); question's too broad though.

Comment: Yup, i'm trying with the "unlink()" but I'm new to PHP, I'm having some trouble with using a button to do it.